# Email Attachment Size Limit

Tags: c#, email, attachment

I am currently using this code in C# to email a file to my hotmail address with an attachment. I ran this and it worked great when attaching a 800KB file, but when I try to attach a 12MB file it just won't do it, I put it in a `try catch` but there were no exceptions, like it just skipped it. The email attachment size limit for hotmail is 25MB, would this affect the email code, or is there a separate limit when doing it through code? Thanks.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("email@hotmail.co.uk");
mail.To.Add("receiving@hotmail.co.uk");
mail.Subject = "Emailed from C#";
mail.Body = "Emailed with attachment";
Attachment attachment;
attachment = new Attachment(@"C:\file.txt");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@hotmail.co.uk", "password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: What if you try to specify content type?

Comment: May not apply, but beware of Hotmail's junk filter. In addition to the Junk Folder, I've also had it silently 'drop' emails I sent through code to @hotmail addresses, even without attachments. It's possible the larger attachment size triggered the spam filter?

Comment: @IaroslavKovtunenko I'm not sure, how do I specify a content type? Thanks!

Comment: BTW, attachment should be disposed after use, though it is not relevant here.

Comment: @Widor Yeah that never crossed my mind actually, that might explain it, thanks.

Comment: @BaliC see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144614.aspx

Comment: Were I you, I would try to triage precisely at which point attachment is dropped. This could give some clue.

Comment: As should `SmtpClient` (be disposed) if you're using .NET 4.0.

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258939/smtpclient-send-attachment-maximum-size

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, cheers for all your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepted answer is Mohamed's link to bug fix question - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=30226