# SmtpClient - Attachment Limits?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, .net-2.0, smtpclient

SmtpClient - .NET 2.0

I was wondering if there is limits of how many attachments you can have?

Comment: I think the number of attachment will depend how much, is the total siz of them. Th Mail server is the one that will limit the attachment size for an individual email. Most of them only allow a max amount of 10 MB, per email.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there is no limitation, but check this question about it you too:

[SmtpClient.Send attachment maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258939/smtpclient-send-attachment-maximum-size)